# Double addition function, how to fix

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, pyqt6

I have a big problem with a part of my code:

the function below, it adds the values of the price column and the quantity column to extract the total amount of the order. But the price column is doubling the value and I can't find the error.

I've tried deleting the variable and clearing the memory cache, thinking it could be accumulating values.. but it's still the same!

This program is using pyqt6 and python3. is a program for issuing sales orders!

````
        global row
        # =============================================== SAVING VALUES INSERTED ON THE MAIN SCREEN IN VARIABLES

        self.obter_resultado = self.ui.comboBox_produto.currentText()
        self.obter_preco = (self.ui.insere_preco.text())
        self.obter_quantide = (self.ui.insere_quantidade.text())
        self.obter_cliente = (self.ui.insere_cliente.text())
        self.obter_prazo = self.ui.comboBox_prazo.currentText()
        self.obter_trasportadora = self.ui.comboBox_transport.currentText()
        self.obter_frete = self.ui.comboBox_frete.currentText()
        self.obter_num_pedido = (self.ui.insere_num_pedido.text())
        self.obter_vendedor = self.ui.comboBox_vendedor.currentText()
        self.obter_embalagem = self.ui.comboBox_embalagem.currentText()
        self.obter_Nf = self.ui.checkBox_NF.isChecked()
        self.obter_Snf = self.ui.checkBox_SNF.isChecked()
        self.obter_obs = (self.ui.observacoes.text())

        # =============================================== INSERTING PRICE, QUANTITY, PRODUCT AND PACKAGING IN THE "PRODUCTS" TABLE

        self.ui.tabela_recebe_produto.setRowCount(len(self.obter_resultado))
        self.ui.tabela_recebe_produto.setItem(row, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(self.obter_resultado))
        self.ui.tabela_recebe_produto.setItem(row, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(self.obter_quantide + " kg"))
        self.ui.tabela_recebe_produto.setItem(row, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("R$ " + self.obter_preco))
        self.ui.tabela_recebe_produto.setItem(row, 3, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(self.obter_embalagem))
        row=row+1

        # =============================================== SAVING VALUES TO A TEXT FILE

        if os.path.isdir(r"C:\\Users\Public\Documents\Pie"):
             print()
        else:
             os.mkdir(r"C:\\Users\Public\Documents\Pie")

        try:
          conteudo1 = open(f"C:\\Users\Public\Documents\Pie\Pedido_{self.obter_cliente}.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8").read()
        except:
          conteudo1 = ""

        if re.search("PEDIDO DE VENDA..\n\nVENDEDOR:", conteudo1):
             arq = open(f"C:\\Users\Public\Documents\Pie\Pedido_{self.obter_cliente}.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
             arq.write(conteudo1+"PRODUTO: %s   |   QUANTIDADE: %s kg   |   PREÇO: R$ %s\r"%(self.obter_resultado, self.obter_quantide, self.obter_preco))
             arq.close()
        else:
             arq = open(f"C:\\Users\Public\Documents\Pie\Pedido_{self.obter_cliente}.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
             arq.write(conteudo1+"PEDIDO DE VENDA..\n\nVENDEDOR: %s\nCLIENTE: %s\nPRAZO: %s\nN°PEDIDO: %s\nNF: %s\nSnF: %s\nTRANSPORTADORA: %s\nFRETE: %s\nPRODUTO: %s   |   QUANTIDADE: %s kg   |   PREÇO: R$ %s\r\n\n Obs:%s\r"%(self.obter_vendedor, self.obter_cliente, self.obter_prazo, self.obter_num_pedido, self.obter_Nf, self.obter_Snf, self.obter_trasportadora, self.obter_frete, self.obter_resultado, self.obter_quantide, self.obter_preco, self.obter_obs))
             arq.close()

        # =============================================== GLOBAL VARIABLE TO CALCULATE FREIGHT
        global qtdd
        global valor
        # =============================================== CALCULATION OF FINAL WEIGHT AND QUANTITY

        valor = valor + float(self.obter_preco)
        qtdd = qtdd + float(self.obter_quantide)

        # =============================================== INSERT THE VALUE IN THE LABEL OF THE WEIGHT AND FINAL QUANTITY

        valor_total = valor * qtdd
        self.ui.recebe_peso_total.setText(str(qtdd))
        self.ui.recebe_valor_total.setText(str(valor_total))```
````

[image: function example image]

Comment: Does the title need to be in capital letter ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you're adding the price which you should not. And why using `global` variable here?

```
        valor = valor + float(self.obter_preco)
        qtdd = qtdd + float(self.obter_quantide)

        # =============================================== INSERT THE VALUE IN THE LABEL OF THE WEIGHT AND FINAL QUANTITY

        valor_total = valor * qtdd
```

Comment: and how will that solve the duplicate sum problem? @answered

Comment: The price should not increase if the customer buy 20kg. For example orange is $10 per Kg, if I buy 10Kg it would be $10 * 10Kg = $100. If I buy 20Kg the price should stay the same, that is $10 * 20Kg = $200.

Comment: I tried to solve the issue here, but I couldn't. Could you please show me the correct way for me to try to run it? @aswered